# Returning output in multiple lines

Tags: python, return

I want to return the output in one line below the other instead of all in the same line
for my code

```
def f(a,b):
  return a,b

f(2,3)
```

So rather than in tuple form I want to return an output like:

```
2
3
```

How can I do that

Comment: Why would you like to do that? It changes for cases.

Comment: you mean you like to return a string `"{}\n{}".format(a,b)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the tuple, I would recommend

```
print(a)
print(b)
```

instead of a return. I don't know, why you would want it to return in different lines, but you could try

```
return a+"\n", b
```

Comment: You can also use string join with new line character.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: And, assuming you convert to str, the result is `('2\n', 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator with yield

```
def f(a, b):
    yield a
    yield b


for x in f(2, 3):
    print(x)
```

Comment: generator is a overkill for simple print.

Comment: @Sushanth yep you are right but it good to know something like this exists

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this

```
 def f(a, b):
   return a, b


 output = f(2, 3)
 print(str(output[0]) + "\n" + str(output[1]))
```